# How to list the files in a folder in windows mobile using C?

Tags: c, filesystems

anyone has an idea how to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using Windows CE? [FindFirstChangeNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms923967.aspx) should do the trick.

Best

Comment: why is it so difficult? is there any easy way like FileInfo in C#?

Comment: If you just want to list the files FindFirstFile()/FindNextFile() should be easier.

If you want to "listen" for changes, then FindFirstChangeNotification() is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest FindFirstFile() and FindNextFile().

Docs with nice example - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364418%28VS.85%29.aspx